# Changing "Table of Contents" header in Org mode

Tags: org-mode

When exporting to HTML, Org produces a TOC with a header (a H2 element) containing the string "Table of Contents". But I often use Org to produce documents in languages other than english, and that english header looks out of place. Is it possible to customize that string somehow?

Of course it can be changed with javascript, but it would be nice if the text was generated correctly in the first place.

Comment: This is a cross-site duplicate: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21239/change-table-of-contents-title-in-org-mode-according-to-document-language